# Problem switch from deprecated Azure Storage Emulator to Azurite in Azure Cloud Service

Tags: azure, service, cloud, emulation, azurite

we are using Azure Storage Emulator (ASE) in the Azure Cloud Service (extended support) project, but as this is deprecated we want to switch to Azurite Emulator (AE). Problem is that if I stop using ASE in Azure Cloud Service (extended support) and manually run AE, it still search for reference in SDK Emulator *(Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceModel....)*

How to correctly switch to AE in the Azure Cloud Service (extended support) project?

Thanks for any hints...

Comment: Where you able to find any solution?

Comment: Hey @Cornel, we postpone this change, but plan to handle soon, will update this thread then.